Why is this code not putting the ICON on the web shortcut>-?
When ran it make 2 seperate icons insead of setting the icon to the web shortcut
I have rewritten this multiple times; I know I need a different host for the ICO file, but I still cannot figure this out`# Apps to make a shortcut for
# Apps to make a shortcut for
$apps = @(
    @{ Name = "Microsoft Word"; Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" },
    @{ Name = "Microsoft Excel"; Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" },
    @{ Name = "Microsoft PowerPoint"; Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.EXE" }
    # Add more applications as needed
)

$websites = @(
    @{ Name = "Tech Support"; Path = "https://support.hmp-tech.com" ; IconPath = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1_9ZU8fNZ60nygs2c1MPUypGj1VQNKNqa" }
)

# Specify the directory where you want to create shortcuts
$shortcutDirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"

# Specify the directory where you want to store downloaded icons
$iconDirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Documents"

# This will make it loop through the programs and allow it to make shortcuts for all
foreach ($app in $apps) {
    $shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut("$shortcutDirectory\$($app['Name']).lnk")
    $shortcut.TargetPath = $app['Path']
    $shortcut.Save()
}

foreach ($website in $websites) {
    $iconFileName = "$($website['Name']).ico"
    $iconPath = Join-Path -Path $iconDirectory -ChildPath $iconFileName
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $website['IconPath'] -OutFile $iconPath
    $shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut("$shortcutDirectory\$($website['Name']).lnk")
    $shortcut.TargetPath = $website['Path']
    $shortcut.IconLocation = $iconPath
    $shortcut.Save()
}


Thank you in advance

Firgure what out? You haven't told us what happens when you run the code :)

A shortcut to an internet page has a .url extension, not .lnk. In there, the location to an icon is set to property IconFile, not IconLocation. It should also have an IconIndex number, usually 0

See this answer on how to create an internet shortcut.
